# Prove that $(1 - \omega)^{\phi(m)} = p$ where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/m}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I was reading Marcus' Number Fields and came across a line saying "we know  $(1 - \omega)^{\phi(m)} = p\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$" where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/m}$ and $m = p^r$. Earlier on in the book it proves that $\prod_{k} (1 - \omega^k) = p$ where the product runs over all k, $1 \leq k \leq m$ such that $p \nmid k$.

But these statements aren't equivalent and I can't see how the proof of the second statement could be reworked to fit the first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that where Marcus says $\omega=e^{2\pi i/\color{red}m}, m=p^r$, and $n=p^{r-1}(p-1)=\phi(m)$?

Comment: Yes, I will add that in now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $\frac{1-\omega}{1-\omega^k}$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ whenever $k$ is coprime to $p$. Of course we have
$$\frac{1-\omega}{1-\omega^k}\cdot\frac{1-\omega^k}{1-\omega}=1,$$
in $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$, where
$$\frac{1-\omega^k}{1-\omega}=1+\omega+\cdots+\omega^{k-1}\in\Bbb{Z}[\omega],$$
so it remains to show that $\frac{1-\omega}{1-\omega^k}\in\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$. For the automorphism $\varphi$ of $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$ mapping $\omega$ to $\omega^k$ you have
$$\frac{1-\omega}{1-\omega^k}=\varphi\left(\frac{1-\omega^l}{1-\omega}\right),$$
for some $l$ coprime to $p$, where
$$\frac{1-\omega^l}{1-\omega}=1+\omega+\ldots+\omega^{l-1}\in\Bbb{Z}[\omega],$$
and hence also $\frac{1-\omega}{1-\omega^k}\in\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$.

Comment: Apologies if this is just me being stupid but I still don't understand. I follow that units map to units under an automorphism, so we have $1 + \omega +  ...  + \omega^{l-1}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ but I don't understand how this brings us closer to our result? Thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: @MylesMckay I'll expand my answer a bit.

Comment: @MylesMckay Is it more clear now?

Comment: I think so, we then have the product of these units (running over all k when k is comprise to p) is also a unit. Then $\frac{(1-\omega)^k}{p}$ is a unit so we have the result we want?